# phonegap как определить включен ли gps?

Tags: phonegap

нашел плагин для получения координат, все работает. 
Но возник вопрос как проверить доступность самого gps и вывести сообщение если надо включить. Как в google картах или навигаторах.

Comment: Теперь надо найти плагин для проверки доступности. А в гуглокартах или навигаторах подобное не используется.